# Execute command program

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, console-application

I am getting the following error while executing a console command program in C#

```
'CutyCaptApp.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded  C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'CutyCaptApp.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0x19a4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x6ac) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'CutyCaptApp.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Srinivasa\VisualStudioProject\CutyCaptApp\CutyCaptApp\bin\Debug\CutyCaptApp.exe', Symbols loaded.
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1d3c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Here is my C# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
   ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
   startInfo.FileName = "C:\\Srinivasa\\VisualStudioProject\\CutyCapt_Pdf_Code\\release\\CutyCapt.exe";
   //startInfo.Arguments = f;
   Process.Start(startInfo);
   //startInfo.FileName =    "C:\\Srinivasa\\VisualStudioProject\\CutyCapt_Pdf_Code\\release\\CutyCapt.exe";    startInfo.Arguments = "--url=C:/Users/UPPALASX/Desktop/New folder/ResearchMap.html --out=C:\\Srinivasa\\VisualStudioProject\\CutyCapt_Pdf_Code\\release\\Out_Embeded_RM.png";
   process.StartInfo = startInfo;
   process.Start();
   process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Where is the error coming from?

Comment: Which operating system are you on? If Windows 7 then trying running VS as administrator and check.

Comment: This is not the error.

Comment: I am unable to open VS as an administrator mode.

Comment: This is not error. This is an output window in visual studio.

Comment: Why do you think there *is* an error in the first place? What did you expect to happen and what did you observe? Did you try to debug the program? You don't have to run Visual Studio as administrator to debug a program.

Comment: It ran successfully,I just closed and re-open the VS it is running. Thanks you guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in the folder path in one of your arguments so it would be being interpreted as two arguments.  Arguments are delimited by spaces so if an argument contains spaces then it must be wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: I have tried with the argument file:///C:/Users/UPPALASX/Desktop/New%20folder/ResearchMap.html but getting same errors

Comment: Did I just imagine myself saying to wrap the path in double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any error in your output. The application may not be behaving as you expect but it's not throwing an obvious error.

Have you tried running the CutyCapt.exe program with the parameters from a command line, rather than from your application to check if it running ok with those parameters?

Comment: yes I ran the CutyCapt.exe using CMD it is ran successfully.My command is : ">CutyCapt.exe --url=file:///C:/Users/UPPALASX/Desktop/New%20folder/ResearchMap.html --out=Out_Embeded_RM.pdf --page-width=800 --page-height=6500"